# Where does iBooks store its documents in Sierra?

Tags: itunes, pdf, books

Late 2011 iMac running macOS Sierra.

I cannot for the life of me find the documents that appear in iBooks.  They are not in my iTunes folder, nor are they in ~/Library/Containers/ (in fact there is no such folder at all), nor are they in ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/ (again there is no such folder).  I do not have iCloud Drive enabled.

So where on earth are all these PDFs and epubs that I can plainly see in iBooks, can sync to my iOS devices via iTunes, etc.?

Comment: It is impossible for you to not have a `~/Library/Containers` folder on Sierra. Make sure you're looking in `~/Library`, the one in your home folder, *not* `/Library`, the one in the root of the startup disk.

Comment: Oh for crying out loud... you're right.  Somehow my existing alias to my user Library folder (that I have used for ages) no longer points to my user Library, but the Root library.  Very weird... but once I realized that then I got to what I needed.  Thanks!  Feel free to put this as an answer if you'd like and I'll accept it.